# Fill Jquery Array from a list of ILists

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to fill a jquery array with several names populated from a back end function.
This is the script:

```
 var availableTags = '@Url.Action("PopSearch", "Home")';
    $("#searchtxt").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });

public ActionResult PopSearch()
    {
        IndustryManager manager = new IndustryManager();
        ProductRangeManager manager2 = new ProductRangeManager();
        ProductCategoryManager manager3 = new ProductCategoryManager();

        IList<Industry> industryList = manager.GetIndustries();
        IList<ProductRange> rangeList = manager2.GetAllProductRanges();
        IList<ProductCategory> categoryList = manager3.GetAllProductCategories();
```

Comment: Why not extract and deliver the names server side as one list instead of three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better performace you can prepeare data on the server side and return it in a single array. On the client side it's pretty simple to modify for using [remote datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote):

```
$("#searchtxt").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("PopSearch", "ControllerName")'
    });
```

**Update**: you can coimbine values like:

```
var result = industryList.Select(x => x.Name)
                 .Union(rangeList.Select(x => x.Name))
                 .Union(categoryList.Select(x => x.Name)).ToArray();
```

Comment: You can combine it using linq. Maybe it's not a best solution but I've added sample.

Comment: Only the first list gets added?

Comment: Something weird is happening, all the items are being added, but only three top get displayed, thats why i wanted to populate the array first and then set that as the source instead of keep on calling the function

Comment: You can call action with ajax request `$.ajax` and the store array in variable which will be used like datasource.